# How to do in htaccess: if file in folder exists, serve it, if not, provide blank.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess file that redirects all requests to `index.php`, so that CMS system can parse the request and provide answer. However for obvious reasons this is not OK for files that actually exist on the requested path (in below case these are files uploaded by users using fck editor), therefore I have one of the rules in htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/fck/(.*) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

This works great, but the problem is, that now I need to create the opposite rule: i.e. when file from folder `/fck/` does NOT exist, then return some blank (or not found or however we want to call it) page and do not bother the CMS with that.

This should be easily (well, OK, easily sounds silly when have to ask this question, but I am not expert to htaccess at all..) done in htaccess. Could someone please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# return /blank.php if no such file or folder in /fck/
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*/fck/.* /blank.php [L]
# or use below line instead of the above line (comment and uncomment accordingly)
# it will display 404 page (using 404 handler from your config: e.g. ErrorDocument 404 /404.php)
#RewriteRule ^.*/fck/.* - [R=404,L]

# your CMS rewrite rules go below
```

**NOTES:**

1) This pattern `^.*/fck/.*` assumes that **fck** folder is a subfolder (e.g. `example.com/one/fck/icon.png`). If **fck** folder is located in website root (i.e. `example.com/fck/icon.png`) then pattern need to be changed to `^fck/.*` as URLs in .htaccess have no leading slash `/` when matching in RewriteRule (unless these rules are declared in server/virtual host context and not .htaccess).

2) I will not say that I'm 100% sure on this (only 99.99%), but these 2 lines are the same:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [QSA,L]
```