# Access subfolders in public folder laravel

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I have a Laravel project, and don not can access a subfolders in a public directory, help please how to add in .htaccess a rule, if request is a folder not redirect to index.php?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Check the folder permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do in htaccess: if file in folder exists, serve it, if not, provide blank.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749139/how-to-do-in-htaccess-if-file-in-folder-exists-serve-it-if-not-provide-blank)

Comment: Michel-  in public folder i have uploads/index.html I want to include to iframe to index page, if I access  direct site.com/uploads/index.html redirect return error, route not found

Comment: This is htaccess code:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
               Options -MultiViews
               RewriteEngine On
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
               RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
           </IfModule>